# Animate divs on scroll into bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, tabs

I'm a real beginner with JQuery and javascript and I've been struggling all day to find a solution to my problem. I hope someone of you might be helpful, it shouldn't be hard.
I'm trying to make some boxes appear as half the viewport height has passed through a declared class. 
I often use this code to make it work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  homeSlide();
});
function homeSlide() {
  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if($('.prev-div').offset().top - $(window).height()/2 < wScroll) {

    $('.boxes').each(function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.boxes').eq(i).addClass('bounce-in');}, 100 *i);
    });
  }
}
```

It always works on a traditional html-css content.  Now it doesn't work, or better, it works, but as soon as the page is loaded, not when I scroll to its proximity. I guess it is  because it is happening inside a bootstrap ".tab-content".  So how do I refer to the ".active .tab-pane" to make the function work as I get closer to the desired point? 
Hope I can solve this thing with your help.
Thanx for your support.

Edit: Here I uploaded a simple representation of the desired effect on JsFiddle, here's the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajsv995L/1/).

How I said it works outside of a "Bootstrap's .tab-content" but not inside of it, I guess I need to offset my function, I tried over and over, but with no positive results.

Comment: Can you give a little more context, or maybe a jsfiddle? Is the `.boxes` class you're trying to animate?

Comment: I'm going to upload further infos as soon as I go home. Anyway, I was wrong saying it doesn't work, it works, but the animation starts as soon as the page is loaded, not when I scroll close to it

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be > instead of <

if($('.prev-div').offset().top - $(window).height()/2 > wScroll)

Comment: no it doesn't work that way. The code is right, it always worked on every other previous websites, it is just because it is part of a "Bootstrap's .tab-content > .tab-pane"

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution myself to the problem: it was necessary to replace  `$(window)` with `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')` on the "if" statement.

```
function homeSlide() {
  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if($('.prev-div').offset().top - $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').height()/2 < wScroll) {

    $('.boxes').each(function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.boxes').eq(i).addClass('bounce-in');}, 100 *i);
    });
  }
}
```

Anyway, now there'a one more problem I can't solve, because the animation fires if I'm scrolling another tab. is there a solution to it?